# I want to install The Ubuntu OS not just the desktop

Tags: upgrade

How will I then uninstall Windows? 
I don't want to run both operating systems side by side.

Comment: What is your question? Ubuntu _is_ an OS, not a "Desktop" whatever that is. If you want to replace Windows with Ubuntu, just format your partition and install Ubuntu over it. Why you would want to do that of course is another matter.

Comment: There are plenty of threads discussed regarding this. This "**[How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)**" will explain, If its a clean install without having to back-up anything.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when installing Ubuntu from e.g. a CD or an USB-stick, you get the chance to purge your complete current running OS ... e.g. Windows. But backup your data first, and check the backups, otherwise your data will be lost.

You can download the `iso` image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and instructions are available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).